# How to clear a value from drop down?

Tags: php, html

```
  $x = date("");
  function add_nol($number,$add_nol)
  {
      while (strlen($number)<$add_nol)
      {
           $number = "0".$number;
      }
      return $number;
  }

  echo "<select name='id'>";
  for($y=10;$y<=100;$y++)
  {
       echo "<option value='". $x."".add_nol($y,3)."'>" . $x."".add_nol($y,3) ."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
```

i have 100 numbers in drop down . once i select a number from it, that number must not be present in the drop down for the next time. how to make that?

Comment: use javascript/jquery for this

Comment: This can be done in PHP: http://pastie.org/8735760